# In Bayes' theorem, what is little $p$?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

In Wikipedia's [conjugate prior article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior), Bayes theorem is given as:

$$p(\theta|x) = \frac{p(x|\theta) \, p(\theta)}
  {\int p(x|\theta') \, p(\theta') \, d\theta'}.$$

What is $p$ here? Is it the density for continuous distributions and the probability mass function for discrete distributions?

Comment: It's the conditional density function, [see remarks here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution)

Comment: @whacka Thanks, the other thing that confuses me is the discrete distribution examples below, do you know what p is in that case?

Comment: With discrete random variables, you just add probabilities, not integrate probability density. So just like it says in parentheses there, $p$ stands for probability. Beyond that, I'm not a probability theorist.

Comment: Remember this is Wikipedia, so it may confuse.  This is implicitly dealing with continuous random variable $\theta$ (as shown by the $\int $; if it was discrete then using a $\sum$ would work instead).  Here (A) $p(x\mid \theta)$ should be representing the *likelihood* of $\theta$ given $x$, proportional to the conditional density (or conditional probability) for $x$ given $\theta$; (B) $p(\theta)$ should be the conjugate prior density for $\theta$; (C) $p(\theta \mid x)$ should be the posterior density for $\theta$ given $x$ and should come from the same conjugate family

Answer (score 0):

$p(A|B)$ means the probability of A being true given the assumed truth of B; “AB” means “A and B”, etc. This basically follows from the fact that “A and B” must always be equivalent to “B and A”.

Comment: Not quite, it's the conditional density function. Do you understand the difference between probability and probability density? For example, consider the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. What is the probability that the value is $\frac{1}{2}$? Well, the probability is $0$ because $\{\frac{1}{2}\}$ has measure $0$ as a subset of $[0,1]$. On the other hand the probability density is $1$. In order the compute the probability of a random variable taking a value within a set, one integrates the probability density over that set. (Indeed, just as one integrates density to get mass in physics.)

Comment: Really? @whacka  Thats interesting; in that case, my teacher made it a lot more difficult that it needed to be.

Comment: I'm guessing you're familiar with discrete random variables but not continuous random variables. Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) for more on probability density. (Also I don't see how you could consider summation to be "a lot more difficult" than integration...)

Comment: @whacka My professor explained it in a way that was a lot more complicated than this; this is the basis for a lot of the work we do in quantum mechanics.